# Killing an input in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, time

Is there a way to simply kill an `input()` from another thread?
For example, if an amount of time has passed, and the user still didn't enter anything in the `input()`, is there a way to simply "kill" the `input()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't kill an `input()`.
However, you could do pretty much the same using `sys.stdin` iterable, for loop and a flag (or some function).

```
import sys

stopReadingInput = False
for line in sys.stdin :
    # Insert some code that involves user input
    if stopReadingInput : # Here you can call a function to check if you don't need user input anymore, instead of if statement. Otherwise you'll have to change the flag value from outside.
        break
```

Comment: Can you give a full example of a code that uses this explanation? Thanks!